# Непонятка с mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Запрос -

```
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT text FROM page WHERE id = '".$pageId."'");
```

выполняется и `echo $q->num_rows;` выводит 1.

Запрос -

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT text FROM page WHERE id=?")){
$stmt->bind_param('i',$pageId);
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->num_rows;
```

выводит 0.

Comment: я про pdo не знаю ничего толком , но у вас в первом запросе `WHERE id = '25'` (в кавычках), во втором случае нет. Вот такая разница

Comment: это синтаксис mysqli . bind_param подставляет вместо ? указаное значение.

Comment: это я понимаю, я вам просто написал про то, что во втором случае будет без кавычек `where id=25` например, в отличие от первого. как это может повлиятьна результат, не знаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед вызовом num_rows используйте [store_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php).


[num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

> Возвращает число строк в результате запроса. Результат выполнения
> mysqli_stmt_num_rows() зависит от того использовалась ли
> mysqli_stmt_store_result() для буферизации результата выборки в
> дескрипторе.

Люди уже натыкались [1][3], [2][4]